# how to add new button to open module url on product view page using custom module

Tags: module, magento-1.9

I want to add new button (Own Measurement) using custom module on product view page along with Add to cart button. on click new button it will redirect module's index.phtml. 
my module config.xml file is:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <SilkSoftware_Measurement>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </SilkSoftware_Measurement>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <measurement>
        <use>standard</use>
          <args>
            <module>SilkSoftware_Measurement</module>
            <frontName>measurement</frontName>
          </args>
      </measurement>
    </routers>
        <layout>
          <updates>
            <measurement>
              <file>measurement.xml</file>
            </measurement>
          </updates>
        </layout>
  </frontend>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <measurement>
        <class>SilkSoftware_Measurement_Helper</class>
      </measurement>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <measurement>
        <class>SilkSoftware_Measurement_Block</class>
      </measurement>
    </blocks>
  </global>
  <admin>
    <routers>
      <measurement>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
          <module>SilkSoftware_Measurement</module>
          <frontName>admin_measurement</frontName>
        </args>
      </measurement>
    </routers>
  </admin>
  <adminhtml>
    <menu>
      <measurement module="measurement">
        <title>Measurement</title>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        <children>
          <measurementbackend module="measurement">
            <title>own measurement</title>
            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
            <action>admin_measurement/adminhtml_measurementbackend</action>
          </measurementbackend>
        </children>
      </measurement>
    </menu>
    <acl>
      <resources>
        <all>
          <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
          <children>
            <measurement translate="title" module="measurement">
              <title>Measurement</title>
              <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
              <children>
          <measurementbackend translate="title">
            <title>own measurement</title>
          </measurementbackend>
              </children>
            </measurement>
          </children>
        </admin>
      </resources>
    </acl>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <measurement>
          <file>measurement.xml</file>
        </measurement>
      </updates>
    </layout>
  </adminhtml>
</config>
```

I create this module with the help of Silksoftware and it show module frontend properly. i want whenever i install module then this button (Own Measurement) add automatically on product view page and on click button it  will redirect to module index.phtml file.